# How do I append a variable on another only if it exists?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Basically I want to append the variables one, two and three only if they have a length > 1.

How can this be done?

```
var params = {
    q: one + two + three;
};
```

Comment: That question doesn't make sense: if `two` is `""` appending it does *nothing*. E.g. `one + "" === one`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to do it based on the variables `length` as a string object:

```
var params = {
    q: (one.length > 1 ? one : "") + (two.length > 1 ? two : "") + (three.length > 1 ? three : "")
}
```

or if you mean to append if the variable has been defined:

```
var params = {
    q: (typeof(one) != "undefined" ? one : "") + (typeof(two) != "undefined" ? two : "") + (typeof(three) != "undefined" ? three : "")
}
```

Comment: As long as `one` is a string, if `one.length === 0` then `one === ""` so that code--while it does exactly what was asked--is completely pointless.

Comment: I understand, I first added what the question *literally* meant, I have now edited it to do what it *might* have meant as well.